# Calling a function inside a const with props in react js

Tags: reactjs, function, modal-dialog, constants, use-state

I have a dashboard and I have a function in it, this is a modal type and it holds a form. When the form is completed, the data entered appears on the table at the bottom of my dashboard.

Presently, the data in the table is loaded quite alright but whenever I click on the button ( that brings up the form, when I type init the form dissapear..basically the form disappears on click.

Here is my code below... thanks

```js
import React, {useState,useContext,useEffect} from 'react';
import TransactionItem from '../components/TransactionItem';
import TransactionService from '../Services/TransactionService';
import Message from '../components/Message';
import { AuthContext } from '../Context/AuthContext';
import { Line, Pie } from "react-chartjs-2";
import {
  Card,
  CardHeader,
  CardBody,
  CardFooter,
  CardTitle,
  Table,
  Row,
  Col,
  Button,
  FormGroup,
  Input,
  Modal
} from "reactstrap";


const Dashboard = props => {
  const [transaction,setTransaction] = useState({amount : "", date : "", token : "", meter : "", transactionid : ""});
    const [transactions,setTransactions] = useState([]);
    const [message,setMessage] = useState(null);
    const authContext = useContext(AuthContext);

    useEffect(()=>{
      TransactionService.getTransactions().then(data =>{
          setTransactions(data.transactions);
      });
  },[]);

 
  function Recharge() {
    
  const [transactionModal, setTransactionModal] = useState(false);

  const onSubmit = e =>{
    e.preventDefault();
    TransactionService.postTransaction(transaction).then(data =>{
        const { message } = data;
        resetForm();
        if(!message.msgError){
            TransactionService.getTransactions().then(getData =>{
                setTransactions(getData.transactions);
                setMessage(message);
            });
        }
        else if(message.msgBody === "UnAuthorized"){
            setMessage(message);
            authContext.setUser({username : "", role : ""});
            authContext.setIsAuthenticated(false);
        }
        else{
            setMessage(message);
        }
    });
}

const onChange = e =>{
  setTransaction({...transaction,[e.target.name] : e.target.value});
  
}

const resetForm = ()=>{
  setTransaction({amount : "", date : "", token : "", meter : "", transactionid : ""});
}


return (

  <>
  <Button
    className="btn-round"
    color="success"
    type="button"
    onClick={() => setTransactionModal(true)}
  >Recharge
  </Button>
  <Modal
    isOpen={transactionModal}
    toggle={() => setTransactionModal(false)}
    modalClassName="modal-register"
  >
    <div className="modal-header no-border-header text-center">
      <button
        aria-label="Close"
        className="close"
        data-dismiss="modal"
        type="button"
        onClick={() => setTransactionModal(false)}
      >
        <span aria-hidden={true}>×</span>
      </button>

      <h3 className="modal-title text-center">Enter Details</h3>
      <p></p>
    </div>
    <div className="modal-body">
      <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
      <FormGroup>
        <label>Amount</label>
        <Input 
          defaultValue="" 
          placeholder="Enter date" 
          name="amount"
          value={transaction.amount}
          onChange={onChange} 
          type="text" />
      </FormGroup>
      <FormGroup>
        <label>Date</label>
        <Input 
          defaultValue="" 
          name="date"
          value={transaction.date}
          onChange={onChange} 
          placeholder="Enter date" 
          type="text" />
      </FormGroup>
      <FormGroup>
        <label>Token</label>
        <Input 
          defaultValue="" 
          name="token"
          value={transaction.token}
          onChange={onChange}
          placeholder="Enter token" 
          type="text" />
      </FormGroup>
      <FormGroup>
        <label>Meter</label>
        <Input 
          defaultValue=""
          name="meter" 
          value={transaction.meter} 
          onChange={onChange}
          className="form-control"
          placeholder="Enter meter" 
          type="text" />
      </FormGroup>
      <FormGroup>
        <label>ID</label>
        <Input 
          defaultValue="" 
          placeholder="Enter Id" 
          name="transactionid" 
          value={transaction.transactionid} 
          onChange={onChange}
          type="text" />
      </FormGroup>
      <Button block className="btn-round" color="default" type="submit">
        Continue
      </Button>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div className="modal-footer no-border-footer">
      <span className="text-muted text-center">
      {message ? <Message message={message}/> : null}
      </span>
    </div>
  </Modal>
</>

) 

  }

    





  
    return (
      <>
        <div className="content">
          <Row>
            <Col lg="3" md="6" sm="6">
              <Card className="card-stats">
                <CardBody>
                  <Row>
                    <Col md="4" xs="5">
                      <Recharge />
                    </Col>
                    <Col md="8" xs="7">
                      <div className="numbers">
                        <p className="card-category">Last Transaction</p>
                        <CardTitle tag="p">315 Units</CardTitle>
                        <p />
                      </div>
                    </Col>
                  </Row>
                </CardBody>
                <CardFooter>
                  <hr />
                  <div className="stats">
                    <i className="fas fa-people-carry " /> Get help
                  
                  </div>
                </CardFooter>
              </Card>
            </Col>
          <Row>
          <Col md="12">
              <Card className="card-plain">
                <CardHeader>
                  <CardTitle tag="h4">Transactions</CardTitle>
                  <p className="card-category">
                    A list of your previous transactions
                  </p>
                </CardHeader>
                <CardBody>
                  <Table responsive>
                    <thead className="text-primary">
                      <tr>
                        <th>Date</th>
                        <th>Amount</th>
                        <th>Token</th>
                        <th className="text-right">Action</th>
                      </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                      
            
                            {
                                transactions.map(transaction  =>{
                                    return  (<tr><TransactionItem key={transaction._id} transaction={transaction} />

                                             </tr>)
                                })
                            }
                        
                
                     
                    </tbody>
                  </Table>
                </CardBody>
              </Card>
            </Col>
          </Row>
      
        </div>
      </>
    );
  }

export default Dashboard;
```

Comment: I have a bad feeling of having <Modal> and Form inside one piece, because any modal or message change, will trigger the Modal to re-render again. If you can structure the code in a way that Form is only happening inside Modal without external input (or limit inputs), that might help. For now, put a console.log inside `onSubmit` and before `return` and see if any variable triggered re-render.

Comment: I did the console log, and I saw this ''Input contains an input of type text with both value and defaultValue props. Input elements must be either controlled or uncontrolled (specify either the value prop, or the defaultValue prop, but not both). Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element and remove one of these props''

Comment: Thanks. I simply deconstruct the code and have the modal as a separate function which I then imported to the dashboard. The form is more stable now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved the modal to another page and imported it into the dashboard. Works fine now.